# Download Directory and Contents

Tags: struts2

Is it possible to persuade the `stream` result to download an entire directory and it's contents? And if so, how? I've no problem getting it to download individual files, but I have a need to download a series of files that must be in a specific directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

Stream result allow you to download ONE content, with its MIME type, its name, etc.

This makes it impossible to work with a lot of files, with different names and content type.

What you can do is:

1. Render in a JSP the list of files (in `anchor` tags for example), everyone targeting the Action that will download that single file;
2. Call multiple Actions via scripting opening multiple pages (`target="_blank"`) for every file you have (dangerous, annoying, almost useless...);
3. Create a zip with Java in server side, containing all your files and directories, then output the zip with Stream result.

I think you may consider the third option.

Comment: Agreed. I'd already considered the zip file approach, but I thought I would check first in case there was something I'd overlooked.